# React Invalid Hook Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I'm new in React and I found an example about my project.I'm trying to run it but I got 
"Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app"

I looked for in internet, there are some explanation but they don't match with my code.So what's the wrong in my code?

```
    getProduct = (response, allBarcodes) => {
    const context = this;
    let buffer = [];
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "/productImages",
      data: { barcode: allBarcodes },
      config: { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } }
    })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        buffer.push(<p>Search Result:</p>);
        buffer.push(<br />);
        response.data.map(data => {
          console.log(data);
          data.map(data => {
            buffer.push(
              <Link to={"details/" + data.BARCODE}>
                <img
                  className="similarProduct"
                  src={data.IMAGELINK.split("||")
                    .reverse()
                    .pop()}
                />
              </Link>
            );

            context.setState({ message: buffer });
          });
        });
      })
      .catch(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        context.setState({ message: "Please try again" });
      });
  };

  getSearchItem = id => {
    const context = this;
    context.setState({ message: "Searching..." });
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "/searchSelectedItem",
      data: {
        img_url: this.state.coordinate[id].img,
        coordinate: this.state.coordinate[id]
      },
      config: { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } }
    })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        let allBarcodes = "";
        response.data.map(
          data => (allBarcodes += data.product.productLabels[3].value + ",")
        );
        context.getProduct(response, allBarcodes);
      })
      .catch(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
  };

  onDrop = files => {
    this.setState({
      message: "Loading...",
      image: "",
      firstItemCoordinate: {},
      files
    });
    let file = new FormData();
    file.append("file", files[0]);
    const context = this;
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "/boundingBox",
      data: file,
      config: { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } }
    })
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status !== 400) {
          context.setState({ coordinate: response.data });
          context.state.coordinate.map(coordinate =>
            context.setState({ firstItemCoordinate: coordinate })
          );
          console.log(context.firstItemCoordinate);
          context.setState({ message: "" });

          let image = new window.Image();
          image.src = context.state.firstItemCoordinate.img;
          image.onload = () => {
            context.setState({
              image: image
            });
          };

          if (context.state.coordinate.length === 0) {
            context.setState({ message: "Object not found" });
          }
        } else {
          context.setState({ message: "Please try again" });
        }
      })
      .catch(function(response) {
        context.setState({ message: "Please try again..." });
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dropzone
          onDrop={this.onDrop}
          accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpg, image/jpeg"
        >
          {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
            <section>
              <div {...getRootProps({ className: "dropzone" })}>
                <input {...getInputProps()} />
                <button className="btn">Upload</button>
              </div>
            </section>
          )}
        </Dropzone>
        <h3>{this.state.message}</h3>
        <Stage
          width={this.state.firstItemCoordinate.imgW}
          height={this.state.firstItemCoordinate.imgH}
        >
          <Layer>
            <Image className="productImg" image={this.state.image} />
            {this.state.coordinate.map((item, id) => (
              <Group key={id}>
                <Rect
                  x={item.x1}
                  y={item.y1}
                  width={item.w}
                  height={item.h}
                  shadowBlur={5}
                  strokeWidth={1}
                  stroke={"red"}
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.getSearchItem(id);
                  }}
                />
                <Label x={item.x1 + item.w - 40} y={item.y1 + item.h}>
                  <Tag
                    fill="black"
                    pointerDirection="down"
                    pointerWidth={10}
                    pointerHeight={10}
                    lineJoin="round"
                    shadowColor="black"
                  />
                  <Text
                    text={item.name}
                    fontFamily="Calibri"
                    fontSize={18}
                    padding={5}
                    fill="white"
                  />
                </Label>
              </Group>
            ))}
          </Layer>
        </Stage>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "xtreme-react-admin",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://wrappixel.com/demos/free-admin-templates/xtreme-reactadmin-lite/",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.1.3",
    "chart.js": "2.7.2",
    "history": "4.7.2",
    "node-sass": "4.6.1",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "1.3.3",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.3",
    "react": "16.4.2",
    "react-awesome-slider": "^1.0.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.4",
    "react-dom": "16.4.2",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "1.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5",
    "reactstrap": "6.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.0.1",
    "react-alice-carousel": "^1.15.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hooks are meant for functional component and your code is seems to be a class component. Where are you using Hooks?

Comment: Actually I'm using hooks nowhere. I'm just calling this component on App.js and rendering to index.html. That's why I'm asking

Comment: Post your `package.json` file.

Comment: added package.json

Comment: I had this error as well, and I wasn't using hooks either. You need to check if you have a duplicate version of React. Check if you see 2 reacts with `npm ls react`

Comment: xtreme-react-admin@0.1.0 
├── react@16.4.2 
└─┬ react-perfect-scrollbar@1.2.0
  └── react@16.4.2  deduped  that's mean I have 2 reacts?

Comment: I don't see any error here. Hooks are added in `React 16.8`, you are using `React 16.4`. I think the issue might be in any external library which might be using hooks.

Comment: It seems to be you have 2 react, try removing 1.

Comment: Yeah you have two reacts. Try checking this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991

Comment: But my all components working correctly except this one.I think I have one react please check this screenshot https://ibb.co/Vpg36Q2 .I upgrade my react to 16.8 but nothing changed.